# Show selected li element after page refresh

Tags: html

So I have this code as below and the number of li elements can vary. Selecting the required element works fine and returns the correct data but I want the clicked li element to remain highlighted and visible after the page refresh. Any thoughts please.

```
<div class="owl-cssmenu bot-60">
  <ul>
    @foreach (var item in (ViewBag.Items as List<Kevspage.Models.ItemsModel>).OrderBy(_ => _.Ndx))
    {
      <li class="clr-a" id="@item.Ndx">
        <a name="selectit" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Bogies" asp-route-id="@item.Ndx">@item.Name</a>
     </li>
    }
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance folks

Comment: There are many duplicates of this question, and many options. It's a challenging question for Stackoverflow because it's hard to recommend specific technologies - there's a "close question" reason for "asking for recommendations" because it's too broad. [Persist variables between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use localStorage for that but ı am not sure about that is best practice